# Two versions of external JAVA API - is it possible to use both in one java app?

Tags: java, windows, api

**quick story:**

1. Big core application but used in two versions.
2. There is a Java API but there are two APIs, not compatible.
3. I have created application in Java (Windows) which uses these APIs (two separate applications). They do the same (for example you can create user in the core application).
4. One API is defined in the classpath for the first application and another in the second application. My code is more or less the same. So I can compile the app and I can use it only for the specific version of the core application.

**goal:**
one application which creates user in both core applications

**questions:**

- A. is it possible to create one application which uses the right API
  after choosing the version of the core app by the user or which will
  create user in the first app and in the second app?
- B. if A is not
  possible and third application is necessary - how should it
  communicate and lunch the first and second one? by args?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Runtime.exec(String)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

It allows you to start an application from within Java.  Be warned that it stumps  people on the path to success as shown by the StackExchange questions about it.

You could write a third application to decide which application needs to be run, then use Runtime.exec to execute that application.